# Determine the location and order of the zeros

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am trying to find the zeroes and the order of them for $$sin^4{\frac{1}{2}}z$$

So $f(z) = 0$ when $sin{\frac{1}{2}}z = 0$ so $z = 0 $ when $z = 2 \pi k$ when k is an integer. Is that right?

What about the order? So do I keep finding derivatives of f(z) until $f^{n}(z) \ne 0$? when  $f(z) = 0$

Is that right? How do I notate this better? How do I write that z is a zero of the function?

Anyway:

$f'(z) = 4 \sin^{3}{\frac{1}{2}z} \cdot cos \frac{1}{2}z \cdot \frac{1}{2}$

by laws of chain rules

Is that right? Do I keep going? My book says it's 4th order but I'm not sure how to get there.

Answer (score 1):

This looks good so far - although finding the derivatives will get progressively harder.
Perhaps a quicker way is to note that $f(z)$ is analytic and consider its power series. Starting with the zero at 0, since $\sin (\frac{z}{2})=\frac{z}{2}+O(z^3)$, raising this to the power of 4 we see that $f(z)=\frac{z^4}{16} +O(z^6)$ and so has a zero of order 4. The other zeros occur at $z=\pi k$ for k an integer, and these are also of order 4 by the periodicity properties of sine.

Comment: Sorry can you clarify what that equation is?

Comment: Hi - I'm not sure what you're referring to by "that equation"?

Comment: the sin(z/2) = z/2 + O(z^3) equation

Comment: This is just the standard power series definition of sine, $\sin (z)=z-\frac{z^3}{3!}+\frac{z^5}{5!}+...$